# Github page is not working, deployment error with Jekyll conversion

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I made some changes on my index.html and style.css, before that GitHub page was working just fine but after the changes it stopped working and it shows the following error.
I don't have any clue what is wrong,

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

Comment: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/220